# Run scalafmtCheck in an sbt assembly

Tags: scala, sbt, scalafmt

I would like to run a  `scalafmtCheck` in `sbt assembly`. I tried to add:

```
(compile in Compile) := ((compile in Compile) dependsOn scalafmtCheck).value
```

I got that error :

```
[error] References to undefined settings: 
[error] 
[error]   submissions / scalafmtCheck from submissions / Compile / compile (/home/yass/Documents/Invenis/iss/build.sbt:45)
[error]      Did you mean submissions / Compile / scalafmtCheck ?
[error] 
[error]   scalafmtCheck from Compile / compile (/home/yass/Documents/Invenis/iss/build.sbt:45)
[error]      Did you mean Compile / scalafmtCheck ?
[error]
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there. `scalafmtCheck` is a task as well, therefore needs scope. What you need to do is:

```
Compile / compile := (Compile / compile).dependsOn(Compile / scalafmtCheck).value
```

If you want to add it to the assembly stage, you can do:

```
assembly := assembly.dependsOn(Compile / scalafmtCheck).value
```

If you want the format to apply this to your tests as well you can do:

```
Compile / compile := (Compile / compile).dependsOn(Test / scalafmtCheck).value
```

Or only at the assembly stage:

```
assembly := assembly.dependsOn(Test / scalafmtCheck).value
```